# The system is running in low-graphics mode

Tags: ubuntu, artificial-intelligence, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia-docker

Im trying to repurpose a Cryptocoin mining rig for AI research.

The operating system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

In order to utilize the graphics cards I need to install Nvidia drivers and Cuda.

However, whenever I restart the box I always get the following error:

> The system is running in low-graphics mode
>   [image]

My question is, how can I tell Ubuntu to not use these drivers? I need them installed, but they are only used by nvidia-docker.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that should help you on ask Ubuntu.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/335285/how-to-change-proprietary-video-driver-using-the-command-line.

Ubuntu 12.04 
You can use jockey-text to disable and enable Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu.
For example:
    •   Run jockey-text --list to get the list of available options.
    •   Run sudo jockey-text -d xorg:nvidia_304 to remove the 304 driver.
    •   Run sudo jockey-text -e xorg:nvidia_304 to enable the same driver.
    •   Run jockey-text --help to see the help manual.